# Как присвоить значение текущей даты тегу <select>

Tags: php, html, html-select

```html
<select id="day">                            
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="05">05</option>
</select>

<!-- Выбор месяца -->

<select id="month">                            
  <option value="09">Сентябрь</option>
  <option value="10">Октябрь</option>
  <option value="11">Ноябрь</option>
  <option value="12">Декабрь</option>
</select>

<!-- Выбор года -->

<select id="year">                           
  <option value="1996">1996</option>
  <option value="1997">1997</option>
  <option value="1998">1998</option>
  <option value="1999">1999</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
</select>
```

Есть необходимость организации на сайте выбора даты именно в таком формате при помощи тега `SELECT`, при этом значением по умолчанию у каждого должна быть текущая дата, соответствующая своему полю.

К сожалению на просторах не нашел ничего подходящего, либо моих знаний катастрофически не хватает. Прошу вашей помощи! Хотя бы направление, где искать...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос. У вас затруднения с тем, как получить текущую дату в php/js/что-там-у вас, или вы не знаете каким образом в html-коде выбирать option по умолчанию, или в чём проблемы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Используйте функции для работы со временем, в сочетании с массивами и циклами:

```
<?php

$months = [
    'Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь',
    'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь',
];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <strong>Необходимо выбрать дату просмотра:</strong>
    <div>
        <!-- Выбор дня -->
        <select id="day">
            <?php $date = date('d'); ?>
            <?php foreach (range(1, date('t')) as $val) { ?>
                <?php $day = sprintf('%02d', $val); ?>
                <?php $selected = ($day == $date ? ' selected' : ''); ?>
                <option value="<?= $day ?>"<?= $selected ?>><?= $day ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>

        <!-- Выбор месяца -->
        <select id="month">
            <?php $date = date('m'); ?>
            <?php foreach (range(1, 12) as $val) { ?>
                <?php $day = sprintf('%02d', $val); ?>
                <?php $selected = ($day == $date ? ' selected' : ''); ?>
                <option value="<?= $day ?>"<?= $selected ?>><?= $months[--$val] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>

        <!-- Выбор года -->
        <select id="year">
            <?php $date = date('Y'); ?>
            <?php foreach (range(1996, 2020) as $val) { ?>
                <?php $selected = ($val == $date ? ' selected' : ''); ?>
                <option value="<?= $val ?>"<?= $selected ?>><?= $val ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Здесь каждый тег `<option>` генерируется в цикле. В условии идёт сравнение с текущей датой - если дата и текущий элемент массива совпадают, тегу `<option>` назначается атрибут *selected*. Возможно вам ещё надо будет весь этот блок кода прописать в контейнере `<form>`.

Comment: Вы даже не представляете, как помогли! Большое человеческое спасибо!!!

Comment: @OlegKasumoff вы можете выбрать мой ответ как правильный, отметив его галкой - и тогда вы тоже примете участие в помощи ещё кому-то, кто будет искать конкретное решение ;-)

Comment: А как поверить здесь, существует ли этот день в выбранном году? Например, 29 февраля.

Comment: @DaemonHK `date('t')` как раз это и задаёт: _t Количество дней в указанном месяце от 28 до 31_

Comment: @Эдуард, оу, проглядел, спасибо за пояснение. Только я так понимаю, что при выборе, например, года, все предыдущие селекты нужно обновлять через AJAX?

Comment: @DaemonHK ну тут уж на ваше усмотрение - в данном примере реализовано только отображение, а для отправки куда либо нужно этот  код как минимум в контейнер <form> определять.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно добавить атрибут `selected` к нужному `option`

```html
<select id="day">                            
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03" selected="selected">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
</select>

<!-- Выбор месяца -->

<select id="month">                            
  <option value="09">Сентябрь</option>
  <option value="10">Октябрь</option>
  <option value="11" selected="selected">Ноябрь</option>
  <option value="12">Декабрь</option>
</select>

<!-- Выбор года -->

<select id="year">                           
  <option value="1996">1996</option>
  <option value="1997">1997</option>
  <option value="1998" selected="selected">1998</option>
  <option value="1999">1999</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
</select>
```