# Определение дня недели в выпадающем списке

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите как решить? 
Я так понял нужно вставить скрипт :

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Moscow');
echo getdate( time() )['weekday'];
```

Но как мне выпадающему списку дать понять что ему нужно работать по этой схеме?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может быть это решение вам подойдёт - [Как присвоить значение текущей даты тегу <select>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/747700/185343)

Comment: Что это за функции? В каком окружении оно работает? Это `CMS` или `framework`?

Comment: Это cms окстор 2.3 
Я хочу создать там в выпадающий список чтобы пользователь клацая по нему видел день недели. (как на скрине)

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать редактируемым режим работы, то делайте это как подразумевает CMS, то есть режим должен быть документом с точки зрения CMS.  Если вам нужен просто список, то сделайте его статикой без всякого пхп.

Comment: не редактируемый, просто список, но что значит статикой? он же должен менять дни недели

Comment: @Alex2222, у каждого дня недели есть порядковый номер, вы просто должны проверять совпадает ли этот номер с некими данными, например, элементом массива. Если да, то выделяете текущий день. Я поначалу не въехал, и подумал что вам даты нужно выводить в том списке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно собрать массив с названиями дней недели и временем, и в цикле собрать элементы , подставляя необходимые значения. Вот пример, но для полноценного отображения понадобится его *подровнять* с помощью jQuery:

```
<?php
// Время работы
$time = '10:00-17:00';
// Выходные
$free = ['Суббота', 'Воскресенье'];

$weeks = [
    'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг',
    'Пятница', 'Суббота', 'Воскресенье'
];

$weeks = array_map(function ($day) use ($time, $free) {
    $length = mb_strlen($day, 'UTF-8');
    $void = str_repeat('&nbsp;', (20 - $length));
    return  in_array($day, $free) 
        ? $day . $void . 'выходной' 
        : $day . $void . $time;
}, $weeks);

$week = date('N');

?>

<select>
    <?php foreach (range(1, 7) as $day) { ?>
        <?php $selected = ($day == $week ? ' selected' : ''); ?>
        <option value="<?= $day ?>"<?= $selected ?>><?= $weeks[--$day] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спс огромное! достилизовать я уже смогу думаю! Я бы неделю это делал! Каждый говорит по своему делать, разные мануалы, 90% которых вообще не то что мне надо, и 50% "советчики" еще те...
Спасибо

Comment: А как можно сделать чтобы изначально шло время работы?

Comment: @Alex2222 вы имеете ввиду, сначала время работы, а потом - дни недели?

Comment: Ну как у меня ан скрине, там выходит "режим работы" и уже по клику по нему или при ховере (лучше наверное по клику) выпадает уже список из дней недели и текущий день активный

Comment: @Alex2222 а, так это просто нужно добавить перед циклом тег option, и прописан в нём "режим работы". Посмотрите в справочнике по HTML как это делается. Ну а если не разберётесь, напишете, позже помогу.

Comment: Я наверное не туда вставляю или что-то надо изменить, оно же выводит текущий день недели, а режим уходит в список. 
https://hkar.ru/RP8g

Comment: @Alex2222 дело в том, что одним только html добиться такого поведения, когда у тега селект выбрано два и более значений, и при этом чтобы поле ввода состояло только из одной строки, при клике на которую появлялся бы выпадающий список с уже выделенным текущим днём, нельзя. Можно сделать либо с активной строкой-заголовком "Режим работы", или с активной текущей датой (как сейчас сделано). Если нужно и то и то (как в примере на фото), то без стилевого оформления не обойтись. Но в этом я не помогу, т.к. дизайном не занимаюсь.